# How to fix this useEffect return?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

```js
useEffect(() => {
  // this part makes error  "=>" (Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function.)

  if (autoSlide) {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      refCurrentSlide.current.setCurrentSlide(
        refCurrentSlide.current.currentSlide + 1 >=
          refTotalSlide.current.totalSlide
          ? 0
          : refCurrentSlide.current.currentSlide + 1
      );
    }, INTERVAL_TIME);
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, [autoSlide, INTERVAL_TIME]);
```

Comment: I've never seen that error. What is emitting it?

Comment: I've never seen that error, but the `return () => clearInterval(interval)`I think that is supposed to be outside the `if` statement

Comment: in message about
"Expected to return a value at the end of arrow function."

Comment: What was the solution?

Comment: useEffect(() => {
    if (autoSlide) {
      setInterval(() => {
        refCurrentSlide.current.setCurrentSlide(
          refCurrentSlide.current.currentSlide + 1 >= refTotalSlide.current.totalSlide
            ? 0
            : refCurrentSlide.current.currentSlide + 1,
        );
      }, INTERVAL_TIME);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(setInterval());
  }, [autoSlide, INTERVAL_TIME]);

Answer (score 0):

```
enter code here useEffect(() => {

// This gets called after every render, by default
// (the first one, and every one after that)
console.log('render!');

// If you want to implement componentWillUnmount,
// return a function from here, and React will call
// it prior to unmounting.
return () => console.log('unmounting...');
```

})

return "I'm a lifecycle demo";
}